# When listening for GPS updates in several short intervals on Android, does the GPS use previous data?

Tags: android, gps, location

Imagine an app that listens for GPS updates in short intervals of 30 seconds (or less - if it gets first fix). There is some time between listening, lets say 10-20 seconds. The question is - if the GPS don't find the fix in first 30s, will it, when listening again in second interval "start from the beginning" or can it somehow use data received during the first interval so that the fix can be obtained more easily/faster?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two items that will affect your ability to get a fix that can be dependent on previous GPS executions:

1) Assistance information for GPS

2) Tracking information maintained by the GPS engine for the GPS satellites in view

For #1:

For GPS location data that you get in an Android app via the LocationListener, most Android phones use something created by Qualcomm called gpsOneXTRA:

http://news.thomasnet.com/companystory/QUALCOMM-Introduces-gpsOneXTRA-Assistance-to-Expand-Capabilities-of-Standalone-GPS-508624

This is considered a type of "assisted GPS" solution, but it retrieves assistance information from a server, typically outside the cell network, over an IP connection.

gpsOneXTRA assistance data is good for up to seven days, although some devices will refresh this data more frequently (e.g., U.S. Sprint Android devices refresh about every 48 hours), since GPS quality will degrade with the age of the assistance data.

So, the assistance data will be retrieved at most once in the first 30 seconds, assuming it hasn't retrieved assistance data in a while.  In the next 30 seconds, this assistance data won't be retrieved again.

More on gpsOneXTRA in the 2010 Sprint App Developers Conference here, on Slide 12 about 19:35 minutes in:
http://developer.sprint.com/site/global/events/pastevents/2010devcon/videos/sprint_enabling_location_services.jsp

For #2:

The internal GPS engine implemented by the phone OEM tracks the satellites in view, and this is somewhat dependent on past GPS observations depending on the GPS sensitivity of the device.  So, the impact of the 10-20 second delay between the GPS listening sessions will depend on the GPS sensitivity of the device.

Most "high-sensitivity" GPS chipsets are able to quickly acquire a GPS fix from a cold start (i.e., no previous GPS observations) in a few seconds or less, depending on the indoor obstruction, so the 10-20 seconds downtime really isn't going to affect your ability to get a fix.  An example is SiRF Star IV:

http://www.sirf.com/products/25/sirfstariv-gsd4t

...that can acquire a GPS fix up to -160dBm.  And note that the tracking engine is sensitive up to -163dBm, so once an initial fix is required it can keep tracking even if the signal worsens.

This is typically good enough to instantly get a GPS fix outdoors with clear view in the sky, and good enough to get a fix indoors in a few seconds without heavy obstructions (e.g., brick, metal, or concrete).  Unless the phone's GPS antenna is horrible or the GPS OEM software is really messed up (which is possible), in modern Android phones with high-sensitivity GPS chipsets the 10-20 sec delay shouldn't have a huge affect on your ability to get a fix.

Mike Lockwood's GPSTest app is a good one to see what satellites your phone can currently see, and you can start and stop GPS observation in the app, so you can see what the affect of the delay can be on your phone's ability to track GPS satellites:

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.android.gpstest

An aside:

The behavior mentioned by Luis is actually a widespread bug on many pre-Jelly Bean 4.1 Android devices.  Some devices do the 11 fixes in a row then rest, others will continuously sample every second no matter what minTime parameter is passed into the LocationManager for the Location Listener.

Full discussion of this issue with the Android team is here:

https://android-review.googlesource.com/#/c/34230/

A new CTSVerifier test has been added in Android 4.1 JellyBean that should prevent this from happening on JellyBean and higher.

Answer (score 1):

My experience with a few devices is that when a new location you will receive 11 calls to onLocationChange(), one per second.

If you set the time between updates for a value smaller then that (11 seconds), the GPS will continuously call onLocationChange() every second with an updated location, without interruption.

If you set the time between updates for a value bigger then that (a few minutes), it will keep call 11 times onLocationChange() and then stop for a few seconds, and will restart after the time with more 11 calls to onLocationChange(). It will not call onFirstFix() again, and there is no time delay acquiring satellites signal.

I've never tried to set the time between updates for a value in the magnitude of hours, so for this I have no idea.

good luck.

Comment: Thanks. It is probably good to know information, but my "delay" was meant as a time where GPS is off. Ie. when you call removeListener().